# Proving a pair of inequalities holds for all real numbers

Tags: real-analysis

Let $0<x<y$. Prove $$\left|y-\sqrt{y^2-x^2}\right|< x$$ and $$\left|y+\sqrt{y^2-x^2}\right|> x$$

I can not figure out how to show this directly nor can I figure out exactly what to prove if I try by contradiction since it should hold for all numbers satisfying $0<x<y$. Any suggestion on showing these in either way would be greatly appreciated.

---

Comment: The second one can be easily proved, as $y\gt x$, so $y+\sqrt n \gt x$.

Comment: You can remove the absolute values, since what's inside is positive in both. Then it becomes obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $a,b$ are non-negative then $a<b\iff a^2<b^2.$

If $y>x>0$ then $ y-\sqrt {y^2-x^2}>y-y=0.$

So for $y>x>0$ we have $$ |y-\sqrt {y^2-x^2}\;|<x\iff y-\sqrt {y^2-x^2}<x\iff$$ 
 $$\iff y-x< \sqrt {y^2-x^2}\iff$$ $$\iff (y-x)^2<y^2-x^2=(y-x)(y+x)\iff$$ $$\iff  y-x<y+x.$$ The last line is obtained by dividing  the values of the previous line by the positive value $y-x.$

Answer (score 0):

Let $t = \frac{y}{x}$ and the inequality becomes

$$ |t - \sqrt{t^2-1} | < 1 $$

and $t>1$. Removing absolute values give

$$ -1 <t - \sqrt{t^2-1} < 1 $$

Now, Let $f(t) = t - \sqrt{t^2-1} $. We have

$$ f'(t) = 1 - \frac{t}{\sqrt{t^2-1}} = \frac{ \sqrt{t^2-1}-t}{\sqrt{t^2-1}}  $$

one can show that $t > \sqrt{t^2-1}$ and thus this gives that $f'(t)<0$ and means $f(t)$ decreases for all $t>1$. In particular, we must have $f(t) < f(0) = 1$

now, also,

$$ \lim_{t \to \infty} 1 - \frac{t}{\sqrt{t^2-1}} = \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{1}{t + \sqrt{t^2-1}} = 0 $$

and thus $f(t) > 0 > -1$.

Answer (score 0):

We can find $\theta < 90^\circ$ such that $\csc \theta = \frac{y}{x}$. The first inequality is equivalent to showing 
$$\left| \csc\theta - \cot \theta\right| < 1$$
We need 
$$\left|\frac{1-\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}\right| = \left|\tan \theta/2\right| < 1$$
which is obvious since $\theta/2 < 45^\circ$